# DllRegisterServer for C# dll?

Tags: c#, com, regasm

Is there an equilivant to DllRegisterServer for C# dll's? I am creating a COM component and I would like to have some custom code run when I regasm the dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled on `ComRegisterFunction`:
http://www.google.com/search?q=ComRegisterFunction

I can't find any documentation on it, which is a little disconcerting, but it appears to be useful for cases like these.

Let us know if it works out.

Comment: I havent had a chance to try this out yet, but thank you for the information. It looks as if it should work.